# Website failed to load CSS and javascript

Tags: networking, html, javascript, css

Website not displaying properly,on checking the network in inspect element i got more than 90 errors like:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
prettify.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
moment-with-locales.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
pushstream.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.easing.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.lavalamp.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.jgrowl.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.swipe.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.hotkeys.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
facebox.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.wysiwyg.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
wysiwyg.colorpicker.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
wysiwyg.table.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
wysiwyg.image.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
wysiwyg.link.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.autocomplete.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
ua-parser.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.datepick.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.ie6blocker.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.colorbox-min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.ba-bbq.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.drafts.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
clipboard.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
autosize.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
sjcl.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
codeforces.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
EventCatcher.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
preparedVerdictFormats-en.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
jquery.markitup.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
set.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
my:177 Uncaught ReferenceError: Codeforces is not defined
    at my:177
(anonymous) @ my:177
my:217 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at my:217
```

I tried using different browsers(firefox,edge) but none of them seems to work. I tried disabling my adblocker and extension and that didnt worked either.
Is there a way to fix this Problem. Codeforces is the only website which is not working properly all other websites are working fine.

Comment: is your system clock correct, including year? the issue is likely on the other end, but worth verifying.

Answer (score 0):

> Codeforces is the only website which is not working properly, all other websites are working fine.

It seems that, for whatever reason, an SSL certificate associated with the website has an invalid date and is causing resources to fail to load (because the HTTPS connection to those resources is effectively broken by that invalid SSL certificate):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
```

> Is there a way to fix this problem?

If you aren't responsible for Codeforces, then likely no. You can try perhaps clearing your browser caches, etc. and trying to reconnect, but if the website (or perhaps a proxy) is delivering an invalid SSL certificate, there often isn't much that can be done on the user's end.

Comment: yeah i looked into that and the SSL certificate was indeed expired,the date on my machine was also a day behind and they updated their certificate and I fixed the time on my machine and now it seems to be working perfectly.Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you got it fixed. =)